# Support multiple languages in a single bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a plan to support several (3 for now) languages in my bot (that has only one now) and I can't decide is it better to have separate bots (one for each language) or a single multilingual bot. For multiple bots pros are that I can specify description/name in correct language and it is not required to ask new users to choose a language (in all bot stores now it is not possible to specify multiple descriptions also). But it is a bit more difficult to maintain them. Anyone has an experience on it and could suggest something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you can manage your multilangual bot as the same way an app or website is internationalized.

Nothing more, nothing less. Just a user preference for the user language and the strings translated for the bot.

I would not worry about the language description: use english. You can always market the bot on different sites using different languages.

Comment: yep, I don't have any technical difficulties with i18n here, my concerns were mostly about bot stores.

Comment: There is no method in API for get user language, you can just ask user - what your language and save it for this user and next use it for tuture messages

Comment: Now you can get the user language!